# Hide row ... from column

Tags: jquery

I have this

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td class="Data">...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td class="noData">...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td class="noData">...</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

with jQuery, when a row (tr) has a column (td) with class "noData", I'd like hide the complete row the result on this table will be

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td class="Data">...</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

You may try below code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("td.noData").parent().hide("fast");
});
```

Or you may want to use **remove()** instead of **hide()** above or even below code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("td.noData").parent().css('display':'none');
});
```

Comment: you can also do $("td.noData").parent().hide(); to hide the row instantly. (same as the second example)

Comment: I'd like to this for a specific div than I find like this $("[id*=mydiv]")

Answer (score 2):

While sarfraz's solution works, I think this code makes a closer analog to the problem description, which is a good thing for readability and later understanding.

```
$("tr:has(>td.noData)").hide();
```

Comment: fyjham beat me to it by mere seconds ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of the tr's that contain TD's with no data simply call:

```
$("tr:has(> td.noData)")
```

Once you have that it's trivial to hide it (just add a `.hide()` to the end).

The relevant selectors are the [Has](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/has) selector and the [parent>child](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/child) selector.